# Add relationship from sql server "view" to table

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an Sql Server View that returns a combination of a few different tables.

Is it possible to add in a relationship from the View to a foreign table so that Entity Framework could pick up on the relationship and add in foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add in a relationship from the View to a foreign table

No.

> so that Entity Framework could pick up on the relationship and add in foreign key constraint?

Entity Framework does not require a relationship to be backed by a foreign key constraint in the database. Even though you cannot add a foreign key constraint on a view in the database, you can still map the relationship in Entity Framework the same way you would for a table. It just won't be detected automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reference a view in a foreign key.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Markpsmith - Thank you! I am new to this blog and trying to use it in better way. I will definitely take your comments and try to implement it.